# Pasing a value from int to string and viceversa in databinding (Flex 4)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have a service where a data is in String format and in my form I have a NumericStepper whose value is an integer. The question is that I need to make a bi-directional databinding with the DataType object that keep the value.

Is there any way I can parse the value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use the parseInt function? to convert from String to int

Answer (score 0):

Just use casting to appropriate type, here is an example with binding on string value of textInput:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:NumericStepper id="stepper" />
        <s:TextInput id="input" text="{data}" change="{data = input.text}"/>
    </s:VGroup>

    <fx:Binding source="String(stepper.value)" destination="data"/>
    <fx:Binding source="int(data)" destination="stepper.value"/>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [Bindable]
            public var data:String = "0";

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

UPD: Added bi-directional databinding by fx:Binding tag. So, stepper.value binds on the data property, and the data property binds stepper.value. TextInput in the example changes data property for testing.

Comment: The question was about two-way binding. I don't think this will work if you add the `@`

Comment: Hi Serge, the question is that the databinding is bidirectional.